# WPF ItemTemplateSelector Never Loads In UI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an ItemTemplateSelector that uses the typical C# code for logic, but that code never even gets called from my ItemsControl. Right now I have just stubbed in ONE of the Selector Display Templates for "StringTemplate" and I have those in my "Parameters" array, yet it never calls selector.

```
 <Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters}">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <local:ReportRun_LaunchView_ParameterTemplateSelector x:Key="TemplateSelector_FormDetails">
                <local:ReportRun_LaunchView_ParameterTemplateSelector.StringTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <fv:WatermarkTextBox
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Margin="0,0,7,0"
                            fv:WpfMvmFocusManager.FocusKey="txtSearchNpi"
                            Text="{fv:OnChangedBinding Path=StringValue}"
                            WatermarkContent="{Binding DataContext.Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </local:ReportRun_LaunchView_ParameterTemplateSelector.StringTemplate>
            </local:ReportRun_LaunchView_ParameterTemplateSelector>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    IsItemsHost="True"
                    Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ItemsControl x:Name="items" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector_FormDetails}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Do you really want to have a *nested* ItemsControl (without even setting its ItemsSource) for each element of the Parameters collection? You probably just wanted to set the ItemTemplateSelector of the outer ItemsControl and not set its ItemTemplate at all.

Comment: You do not set an `ItemsSource` on the items control that uses the template selector, which means _no item will be generated_, so of course the selector is never called.